# ASP error '80004005' when executing an MA Access multi-line query with subqueries with Left Joins

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, subquery, ms-access-2010

The error is on a classic ASP page, when I am executing a large Access query with subqueries and left joins. Please note that the same ASP code works well with many other queries (smaller ones with no more than one left joins) throughout the same web page as well as in other ASP pages, so the error must have to do with this query itself in my opinion, I just don't know why ASP is throwing an error and it is not working.

The error is generated on the line --> Set rst = connn.Execute(sqlstr) The error points to this line and says "error '80004005'" and doesnt say anything else. The same query (with % replaced with *) runs absolutely fine in MS Access without any error. The code from ASP page is below, followed by the query when printed on page (or in MS Access), I included line breaks here so it will make it easy to read it:

```
Dim Connn
Dim rst
Set connn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data          
Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Database1.accdb")

Dim sqlstr

sqlstr = "SELECT Left(cdate(mid(KPISource.ddate,5,2) & '/' & right(KPISource.ddate,2) & '/' & left(KPISource.ddate,4)), 10) AS [Period ended], CR.[Current Ratio], AT.[A/R Turnover Ratio], AT.DSO, GM.Margin, ICR.[Interest Coverage Ratio], ETR.[Effective Tax Rate], DE.[Debt Equity Ratio]"
sqlstr = sqlstr & " FROM (((((KPISource LEFT JOIN (SELECT ddate, Round((Avg(val) / (Select Avg(val) From KPISource where account = 'LiabilitiesCurrent' and sic=3290)), 3) AS [Current Ratio] FROM KPISource WHERE account='AssetsCurrent' and sic=3290 GROUP BY ddate)  AS CR ON KPISource.ddate=CR.ddate)" 
sqlstr = sqlstr & " LEFT JOIN (SELECT ddate, Format((Avg(val) / (select avg(val) from KPISource where sic=3290 and (account Like 'AccountsReceivablesNetCurrent%' or account Like 'ReceivablesNetCurrent%'))), 'Fixed') AS [A/R Turnover Ratio],"
sqlstr = sqlstr & " IIF(Format([A/R Turnover Ratio], 'Fixed')='0.00','0.00',Format((365 / [A/R Turnover Ratio]), 'Fixed')) AS DSO FROM KPISource WHERE sic=3290 and (accou.....etc...
Set rst = connn.Execute(sqlstr)
```

Full Query when printed on page or in MS Access is below (in ASP page, i already replaced the * with %):

```
SELECT Left(cdate(mid(KPISource.ddate,5,2) & '/' & right(KPISource.ddate,2) & '/' & left(KPISource.ddate,4)), 10) AS [Period ended], CR.[Current Ratio], AT.[A/R Turnover Ratio], AT.DSO, GM.Margin, ICR.[Interest Coverage Ratio], ETR.[Effective Tax Rate], DE.[Debt Equity Ratio]
FROM 

(((((KPISource LEFT JOIN (SELECT ddate, Round((Avg(val) / (Select Avg(val) From KPISource where account = 'LiabilitiesCurrent' and sic=3290)), 3) AS [Current Ratio] FROM KPISource WHERE account='AssetsCurrent' and sic=3290 GROUP BY ddate)  AS CR ON KPISource.ddate=CR.ddate) 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ddate, Format((Avg(val) / (select avg(val) from KPISource where sic=3290 and (account Like 'AccountsReceivablesNetCurrent*' or account Like 'ReceivablesNetCurrent*'))), 'Fixed') AS [A/R Turnover Ratio], IIF(Format([A/R Turnover Ratio], 'Fixed')='0.00','0.00',Format((365 / [A/R Turnover Ratio]), 'Fixed')) AS DSO FROM KPISource WHERE sic=3290 and (account='Revenues' or account='SalesRevenueNet' or account='SalesRevenueGoodsNet') GROUP BY ddate)  AS [AT] ON KPISource.ddate=AT.ddate) 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ddate, Format((Avg(val) / (select avg(val) from KPISource Where sic=3290 and account='Revenues' or account='SalesRevenueNet' or account='SalesRevenueGoodsNet')), 'Percent') AS Margin FROM KPISource WHERE account='GrossProfit' and sic=3290 GROUP BY ddate)  AS GM ON KPISource.ddate=GM.ddate) 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ddate, Format((Avg(val) / (select Avg(val) from KPISource WHERE account='InterestExpense' and sic=3290)), 'Percent') AS [Interest Coverage Ratio] FROM KPISource WHERE sic=3290 and (account='IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeIncomeTaxesMinorityInterestAndIncomeLossFromEquityMethodInvestments' or account='IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeInterestExpenseInterestIncomeIncomeTaxesExtraordinaryItemsNoncontrollingInterestsNet' or account='EarningsBeforeInterestAndTaxes') GROUP BY ddate)  AS ICR ON KPISource.ddate=ICR.ddate) 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ddate, Format((Avg(val) / (select avg(val) from KPISource Where sic=3290 and (account='IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeIncomeTaxesMinorityInterestAndIncomeLossFromEquityMethodInvestments' or account='IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeInterestExpenseInterestIncomeIncomeTaxesExtraordinaryItemsNoncontrollingInterestsNet' or account='EarningsBeforeInterestAndTaxes'))), 'Percent') AS [Effective Tax Rate] FROM KPISource WHERE account='IncomeTaxExpenseBenefit' and sic=3290 GROUP BY ddate)  AS ETR ON KPISource.ddate=ETR.ddate) 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ddate, Format((Avg(val) / (select avg(val) from KPISource where sic=3290 and Not (account Like '*LiabilitiesAnd*') and (account Like '*StockholdersEquity*' or account Like '*Shareholders*'))), 'Percent') AS [Debt Equity Ratio] FROM KPISource WHERE sic=3290 and Not (account Like '*Repayments*' or account Like '*Proceeds*' or account Like '*Payments*' or account Like '*Forgiveness*') and (account Like '*Debt*' or account Like '*NotesPayable*' or account Like '*LeaseObligations*' or account Like '*LinesOfCredit*' or account Like '*Borrowings*' or account Like '*Loans*') GROUP BY ddate)  AS DE ON KPISource.ddate=DE.ddate

WHERE (CR.[Current Ratio]) Is Not Null and (AT.[A/R Turnover Ratio]) Is Not Null and GM.Margin Is Not Null and (ICR.[Interest Coverage Ratio]) Is Not Null
GROUP BY KPISource.ddate, CR.[Current Ratio], AT.[A/R Turnover Ratio], AT.DSO, GM.Margin, ICR.[Interest Coverage Ratio], ETR.[Effective Tax Rate], DE.[Debt Equity Ratio];
```

Where am I going wrong in the code? Any help is highly appreciated. Also, as a side note, I increased the Response Buffering Limit to 64 MB and set Queue time out and session timeout to 2 minutes on the IIS server and restarted it as well, still no result.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, but have no reason why it worked. All I did was this: Based on suggestion from HansUp, I tried executing the query with just one left join, it worked. Then I added a 2nd left join, it worked, then I added a 3rd & so on until the last one. And now it works!

I did not change anything or corrected anything. I simply did above and it works now. Not sure if ASP parsing or ADo takes some time etc. but it works, so just wanted to let anyone know who might have reviewed the question.